# Ionic Framework Android Build Failure

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, localnotification

I'm Facing an Issues while Building an android app on an Ionic framework like follows.
Currently working on Ionic LocalNotifications.

By following this link.

https://github.com/digitaldrummerj-ionic/ionic-local-notifications-sample

[image]

Comment: try this comand `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"`

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach Thanks. It is working for me. You saved really my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update your Android SDK packages to include the missing support library. You can open SDK Manager and install all recommended/pre-checked packages if you are unsure which you need, but the support packages are under Extras in the SDK Manager. To get to SDK Manager, you can run `$ android` in the terminal or open "SDK Manager.exe" from your SDK install path.